# How to obtain the # of people that have a field lte a certain number in a mongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**I'm trying to obtain the # of results in a mongoDB collection using aggregation f and a $lte expression.** '

I've entered the following command and didn't work.

`db.blood.aggregate( [ {$group: {_id:null, "lte_c":{$lte:["$bioquimica.Colesterol",43]}}}])`

The command failed and shows an error:

> "errmsg" : "The $lte accumulator is a unary operator"

The following text is an example of my mongoDB data collections:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either run [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) with [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "bioquimica.Colesterol": { $lte: 43 }
        }
    },
    {
        $count: "lte_c"
    }
])
```

or [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            lte_c: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $lte: [ "$bioquimica.Colesterol", 43 ] }, 1, 0 ] } }
        }
    }
])
```

If you don't need to run this as a part of `aggregate` you can use [count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

```
db.collection.count({"bioquimica.Colesterol": {$lte: 43}})
```

Comment: Why use aggregation framework at all? It's perfectly doable with a "normal" query.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev OP mentioned "using aggregation" so maybe it's a part of larger query but I'll add one more approach

Comment: Ah, missed that.